# how do you create a relevant autocomplete in Solr?

Tags: solr, autocomplete

schema.xml

```
    <fieldType name="text_autocomplete" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" />
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>


    <field name="itemName" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="itemNameAutocomplete" type="text_autocomplete" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="itemNameShow" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" />

    <copyField source="itemName" dest="itemNameAutocomplete"/>
    <copyField source="itemName" dest="itemNameShow"/>
```

http://oi40.tinypic.com/21azfao.jpg

Above is my schema.xml definitions and the image is for the autocomplete i am trying to build using Solr. I want to know how can i prioritize the words that contain "knight" as the first word.
For example in the list "White Knight" is first (i think because it scored a larger amount of items found with that name) and "Knight Errant" is 3rd. This way is not a very good autocomplete solution.

The query i am using is:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=itemNameAutocomplete:"knight"&q.op=AND&rows=0&facet=true&facet.field=itemNameShow&facet.mincount=1&facet.limit=500&wt=json
```

The way that should work is to show "Knight Errant" first followed by "Knight Exemplar" and so on (all the phrases that start with "knight") and only after that show those that don't start with "knight" but contain that word in the phrase.

Any suggestions?